# Why is the else statement still printing after the if statement is satisfied?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow but I had a problem while coding. I created this simple 
program but I noticesd that it still printed the else statement after it was done with the if statement. The code is written in c++ and your help is deeply appreciated.

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char check;
    bool done = false;
    while(not done)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter one of the options provided below."<<endl;
        cout<<"D = distance S = second F = first"<<endl;
        cin>>check;
        if(check == 'D')
        {
            cout<<"You pressed D"<<endl;
        }
        if(check == 'S')
        {
            cout<<"You pressed S"<<endl;
        }
        if(check == 'F')
        {
            cout<<"You pressed F"<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<"You suck!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example, when I press D, I only want to receive `You pressed D`as the output. Instead I get `You pressed D You suck!`

Comment: It'll always tell you that you suck unless you press F. Or did you expect something else? :)

Comment: This is because the `else` belongs to the last `if`.

Comment: Ah thanks! I automatically assumed that the if statement was meant for all the if statements, not only the last one. :D I've spend a good amount of time trying to figure it out and this site answered it in a couple of seconds!

Comment: Use a single `switch` statement instead of a series of `if else` statement.

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure you wanted `else if` (i.e. nested) instead of (subsequent) `if`s, but that's just a guess since you provide no input or output.

Answer (score 4):

Not too often that I think just posting the exact code is the best way to educate but in this case I think the difference will jump out at you:

```
   if(check == 'D')
    {
        cout<<"You pressed D"<<endl;
    }
    else if(check == 'S')
    {
        cout<<"You pressed S"<<endl;
    }
    else if(check == 'F')
    {
        cout<<"You pressed F"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout<<"You suck!";
```

Make sure you understand the difference between `if`, `else if`, and `else`.

Also this is a standard situation in which to use a `switch` statement instead.